# Sending Arrow keys as a string through putty terminal to AIX 7.2

Tags: c#, .net, putty, aix

everybody,

I am breaking my head with some trouble.

I am connecting to AIX 7.2 through PuTTy SSH and I am using a terminal program over there in which I need to move the cursor to choose options.

And, I am too lazy to do it manually when it's something which can be done automatically.

[image: Program]

We have had problems doing the "normal way", by Setting focus on the PuTTy window and sending keys, specially because if it goes too fast, the terminal does not respond well and the keystrokes / text sent is lost... If waiting for too long, either the session goes down. And, finally, even if the focus is being redirected constantly to the window, there is a risk of losing focus. When that happens, part the keystrokes / text is also lost...

So, my major problem is making sure that all the keys are sent. In order to do that, I made a Windows forms in which I detail the options I want and later call a plink.exe process with no window.

I redirected Process.STDO to my form, so that I get a feedback on how is it going the process and, since sometimes info was lost, I have made some kind of a semaphore, to guarantee I write when I finally got feedback from AIX server and for Process.STDIN I use a string array with the text and escaped keys I want to send.

My problem, now:

Since I cannot use SendKeys because I have no window to set focus on, I am trying to use ASCII escape characters to send 'down arrow' key.

Up until now, I am able to send '\n' and normal text, but I cannot send arrow keys for moving up and down and choosing the options, or they are not interpreted correctly.

I have been doing my research, and I have tried sending '\033[1B' (last of many I tried) for moving the cursor down, I used cat command on AIX, so I could see what would print whenever pushing the keys (and prints nothing -non printable character, I guess-) I even downloaded AIX 7.2 manual, to see if there was something useful there...

The main idea, when I am so close of completing it, would be getting 'arrow down' escaped keys value on a string so I can send it through PuTTy, get it recognised and move the cursor up and down.

So, any ideas are welcome...

Comment: I tried "\033[1B", "\033[B", "\E[1B", "\E[B", "\e[1B", "\e[B", "\016" (which actually, when I use echo, throws a non printable character, but when sent, does not move the cursor down)

Comment: try to exec `set -o emacs` and then the program with menus.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at setting ESCDELAY in the process environment.
It is documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=concepts-curses-library).

EDIT: Since the URL didn't work, I did a bit of work. I am posting this other just in case it's useful for everybody.

Comment: I will tell you and @RomeoNinov when I have it done. I temporarily made a mess which is working, but doesn't fix my problem. I am going back with this matter and I will post the solution.

I really appreciate the help both of you have given me